# Using previous table in pig group syntax after filter

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose I have a table in pig with 3 columns, a , b, c. Now suppose I want to filter the table by b == 4 and then group it by a. I believe that would look something like this.

```
t1 = my_table; -- the table contains three columns a, b, c
t1_filtered = FILTER t1_filtered by (
   b == 4
);
t1_grouped = GROUP t1_filtered by my_table.a;
```

My question is why can't it look like this:

```
t1 = my_table; -- the table contains three columns a, b, c
t1_filtered = FILTER t1_filtered by (
   b == 4
);
t1_grouped = GROUP t1_filtered by t1_filtered.a;
```

Why do you have to reference the table before the filter? I'm trying to learn pig and i find myself making this mistake a lot. It seems to me that t1_filtered should equal a table that is just the filtered version of t1. Therefore a simple group should make sense, but i've been told you need to reference the table from before. Does anyone know whats going on behind the scenes and why this makes sense? Also, help naming this question is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have De-referenced(.) is also not correct. This is how it should be.

```
A = LOAD '/filepath/to/tabledata' using PigStorage(',') as (a:int,b:int,c:int);
B = FILTER A BY a==1;
C = GROUP B BY a;
```

But your way of dereferencing(.) will also work in some cases. You can only use dot(.) when you are referencing a complex data type like a map,tuple or bag. If we use dot operator to access the normal fields it would expect a scalar output. If it has more than one output then you will get a error something like this.

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (1,2,3), 2nd :(2,2,2)
```

Your way of using the dot operator would work only if the output of your `group by` has only one output if not you will end up with this error. Relation B is not a complex data type that is the reason we do not use any dereferencing operator in the `group by` clause.

Hope this answers your question.